# Regex to detect end of line(\n) that has double slash(//)

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex for this example:

```
    //This is a comment and I need this \n position
    String notwanted ="//I do not need this end of line position";
```

Comment: Did you want to match that newline character? Any attempts from your side?

Comment: What're you trying to do with that newline character?

Comment: I am working on the reshape of codes, so i would need position to break it properly. I only managed to detect comments but have no idea how to include the \n

Comment: try `"(?<=//[^\\n]{0,999})\\n"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?<!")\/\/[^\n]+(\n)
```

you can use `Matcher` method `matcher.start(1)` to get index of `\n` character, but in will not match String where `\\` is preceded by `"`. Example in Java:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String example = "//This is a comment and I need this \\n position\n" +
                "String notwanted =\"//I do not need this end of line position\";";
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<!\")//[^\\n]+(\\n)");
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(example);
        while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.start(1));
        }
    }
}
```

however it would be enough to use:

```
(?<!")\/\/[^\n]+
```

and just use `matcher.end()`, to get start position of new line.

Another case, if you would like to split a string using this position, you can also use this one:

```
example.split("(?<=^//[^\n]{0,1000})\n");
```

The `(?<=^//[^\n]{0,999})` means:

- `?<=` - lookbehind,
- `^//` - beginning of a line, fallowed by // comments sign
- `[^\n]{0,1000}` - multiple characters but not new lines; here is tricky thing, as lookbehind need to have defined lenght, you cannot use quatifires like `*` or `+`, this is why you need to use interval, in this case, from 0 to 1000 characters, but be aware, if your comment is more than 1000 characters (not too possible but still possible), it will not work - so set this number (1000 in this example) carefully
- `\n` - new line you are looking for

but if you would like to split whole string in multiple places, you will need to add modifier `(?m)` - multiline match - on the beginning of regex:

```
(?m)(?<=^//[^\n]{0,1000})\n
```

but I'm not entirely sure

**>>EDIT<<** response to questions from comments

Try this code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String example =
                "//This is a comment and I need this \\n position\n" +
                "String notwanted =\"//I do not need this end of line position\";\n" +
                "String a = aaa; //comment here";
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?m)(?<=(^|;\\s{0,1000})//[^\n]{0,1000})(\n|$)");
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(example);
        while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.start());
        }
        System.out.println(example.replaceAll("(?<=(^|;\\s{0,1000})//[^\n]{0,1000})(\n|$)", " (X)\n"));
    }
}
```

maybe this regex will fulfill your expectations. If not, please redefine and ask another question with more details like: input, expexted output, your current code, your goal.

Comment: It works like a charm. If possible, i would need to not match `"String notwanted =\"//I do not //need this //end of line position\";";` as well

Comment: @m.cekiera Thank you so much. It worked for the example given above. There is still one last problem on my hand. I know my example might be very vague and i apologize for that. If i add another comment like `//This is another new comment` in a newline. It doesn't capture the position of that line. Thank you for your time and once again i apologize for the inconveniences that you experienced.

Comment: @Sean it happen probably because there is no `\n` character on the end of this new comment. So try to replace `\n` in the end of regex with `$` (end of line metacharacter), like: `(?<=^//[^\n]{0,1000})$` and give me a feedback

Comment: @m.cekiera i try adding \n behind it didn't worked that's why i post to inform you. I also tried replacing the \n with $, however this time i didn't capture anything. There is also another issue with capturing this:String myStr = "asasdasd"; //I need this pos as well

Comment: @Sean so you want to get the end position of every valid Java comment? this is different thing than what you asked in question. And what you do with it? Please add fragments of your code to your question, or some more details, because it hard to determine what is wrong, because for me it works

Comment: @m.cekiera Iapologize for the vague description. Basically what i want is what you have describe. Basically the common scenarios of programmer using (//) for comments are:   
1) //I need this end position with usually ends with a '\n'  
2) String s=" Example"; // I also need this  
Is that clearer?

Comment: @m.cekiera. Thank you this is what i was looking for. Thanks again for your time and explanation. =)

Comment: @m.cekiera. Hey, sorry to bother you again. There is one last issue it won't detect: `"{ //\n"`. I hope you can help with this. Thank you

Comment: @Sean try with: `(?m)(?<=(^|(;|\{)\s{0,1000})//[^\n]{0,1000})(\n|$)`. I added `(:|\\{)`, so it can match if there is nothing (`^`), a semicolon (`;`) or curly open bracket (`{`) before `\\` coment metacharacter

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. It's really really awful. Couldn't really think of a much better, versatile solution. I'm assuming you also wanted comments like this:

```
String myStr = "asasdasd"; //some comment here
```

---

```
^[^"\n]*?(?:[^"\n]*?"(?>\\"|[^"\n])*?"[^"\n]*?)*?[^"\n]*?\/\/.*?(\n)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sQ9oK6/1)

Comment: Thanks it works as well, but i need to not match `"String notwanted =\"//I do not //need this //end of line position\";";` as well

Comment: "@iismathwizard" Thank you so much. It worked for the example given above. There is still one last problem on my hand. I know my example might be very vague and i apologize for that. If i add another comment like `//This is another new comment` in a newline. It doesn't capture the position of that line. Thank you for your time and once again i apologize for the inconveniences that you experienced.